# css bold first word

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I bold the first word of sentence using CSS selectors and is this a good/bad way to do this with respects to browser comparability?

code:

```html
<h2>this is a sentence</h2>
```

Comment: Not sure what you're referring to about browser compatibility.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is no `::first-word` pseudo-element in CSS; you'll have to wrap the first word in an extra element and then select that.

Comment: I'd go for <span class="firstWord">(The first word)</span>.

Comment: Its true, there only :first-letter. But you can do this with javascript, e.g. jQuery `$('h2').each(function(){
     var $p = $(this);
     $p.html($p.html().replace(/^(\w+)/, '<strong>$1</strong>'));
});`

Answer (score 2):

The current CSS selectors do NOT allow this.

So I change my approach to bold the first line.

**HTML**

```
<h2>this<br> is a sentence</h2>
```

**CSS**

```
h2::first-line{
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Span class

So creat a class called bold and wrap first word in the class.

```
.bold {
font-weight:bold;
}
```

Then

```
<h2><span class="bold">the</span> brown fox</h2>
```

Comment: class names such as 'bold' embed presentation info in the HTML, which is generally not great. What if, one day, we decide that the first word should be italic, not bold?

Comment: FFA it's just for explanation, could be called eric

Comment: also, there is no "Spanish" element in HTML.

Comment: @Beejamin The technique is still correct though. Add a span inside the <h2> with a class to make one word a different style

Comment: Looks right to be, but then again I failed Spanish class in high school. (sorry couldn't help it) span is how I would accomplish this if I needed to

Comment: I disagree that this is a good example of the technique - the class names you choose are important. 'Eric' doesn't mean anything, and doesn't tell anyone looking at the markup why the span is there. 'Bold' tells you what the developer was trying to do, but not why. 'firstWord' is better - as it explains what the element is doing in the markup.

Answer (score 1):

I have put the word between `<b>First</b>`

Comment: The <b> tag is kinda being shunned. You should use css or <strong></strong>

Comment: It's not that it's being "shunned," it's that strong tag is used where there is semantic emphasis, while b tag is purely typographical.

Comment: It is funny that this downvoted solution may have more sense sometimes that using <strong>, because I think that to always bold the first word in some sentences, is going to be a typographical decision/design decision, not meaning in reality that those words have true semantic emphasis.

Comment: MayorMonty, Forest, Vicenteherrera and others interested: There is an easy way of explaining the difference between <b></b> and <strong></strong>. Just ask the question 'Why the <b> tag?' and you get the answer that the contents of this tag needs to be emphasised in a strong way, in comparison with the rest of this text. It's a question you do not have to ask for the <strong> tag. So when this question appears to be redundant your on the right track ;)

Answer (score 1):

just put the first word in a strong tag.

```
<h1><strong>This</strong> is how you do it simply.</h1>
```

Here is the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shanehussainnaqvi/323ffa2b/1/)

Answer (score 1):

If PHP is an option:

```
$string = "I've got a wonderful feeling";
$arr = explode(' ',trim($string));
$first = $arr[0];
$all_but = str_replace ("$first ","",$string);
```

This will give you both the first word plus the balance of the string. Then you can style each separately. Undoubtedly there is a smoother option for the $all_but.