# Color the First word of Sentence CSS

Tags: html, css

I was trying to color just first WORD of sentence

```
<div class="logoS">Title Of The Page</div>
```

CSS which am using is

```
.logoS{
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    border:solid 1px black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.logoS::nth-word(1) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

i just want to color "TITLE" not other words, any solution

Comment: I don't think there is a css solution. You will have to use javascript.

Comment: Similar thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440572/css-bold-first-word

Comment: There is no selector for first word (except in the sense that you can wrap the first word in an element and refer to it). There are several existing question on this.

Comment: @Juanid Farooq How about using `content` property . http://jsbin.com/mufolirasuwo/1/edit

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this, hope this will help .

```css
.logoS:before {
  color: red;
  content: "Title ";
}
```

```html
<div class="logoS">Of The Page</div>
```

Comment: i didn't did that sir, i don't know who did that am sorry for that

Comment: am selecting your answer , it helps a lot thanks

Comment: You're most welcome. juanid Farooq

Thanks @drneel for editing my mistake, class name was wrong in css.

Answer (score 4):

The code

```
<div class="logoS"><span id="first">Title</span> Of The Page</div>

.logoS{
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: blue;
    border:solid 1px black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22px;
}

#first {
  margin-right: 20px;
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a span with preferred style for the first word like

```
<div class="logoS"><span class="spanstyle">Title </span>Of The Page</div>

// CSS
.spanstyle {
  color:blue;
}
```

Check this [link](http://www.dynamicsitesolutions.com/javascript/first-word-selector/) . There is `:first-letter` and `:first-line`, but no `:first-word`.

Comment: yeah i know it is possible through this but i want to do this through CSS3's technique like ::first-word

Comment: Your problem is that you assume CSS3 has such a feature.

Comment: CSS doesn't have that feature, you probably read this blog, which is arguing for such a feature: http://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/

Comment: yeah am sorry for that , i assumed that

Answer (score 1):

Use a span tag, this way it won't start a new line.  For example:

```
<div class="logoS"><span id="title">Title</span> Of The Page</div>
```

and then in your css just add:

```
#title{
color: red
}
```

Hope this works!

Comment: sir is there any why to do this through ::first-word ?

Comment: CSS doesn't have that feature, you probably read this blog, which is arguing for such a feature: css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything

Answer (score 0):

There is :first-letter and :first-line, but no :first-word ([MDN Search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=first-word)).  Just wrap your first word in an element.  [Fiddle exmaple](http://jsfiddle.net/cexh12re/)

```
<div class="logoS"><span id="first-word">Title</span> Of The Page</div>

.logoS{
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: blue;
    border:solid 1px black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22px;
}

#first-word {
  margin-right: 20px;
    color: red;
}
```

Or you can use javascript (here's an [example](http://www.dynamicsitesolutions.com/javascript/first-word-selector/)), but if you look at the code, all he does is wrap the first word in a span and add a class.