# How do i spilt words and assign css colors for each word?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

I would like to split the word in javascript or jquery and add assign css colors for "Hear(blue)" and "Us(black)".

Below is the inspect element, and since i don't have file to work on so i would like to work with the class names and id's with inspect element.

For Eg:-

```
$va = $("#section-56 .mid-content h1 span").text().split("");

alert($va);
```

And how to i assign "Hear text as blue and Us text as Black"?

(The above code alert is not working, and i dont know whether this is correct).

Like this i have to get the string and split.

Comment: not sure wether thats the correct code or not, but youre splitting at a empty string insted of space. try   .split(' ') instead

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] of the HTML? (Not backend code...)

Comment: are you able to give the span an id? and why do you want to do it with javascript? is this a static text? then edit the css directly. or do you want to dynamically change the color?

Comment: CSS based answer using `:before` http://stackoverflow.com/a/25561541/1089331

Comment: @Lightningbear no i cant give any class/id since i dont have file with me. so thats why im using class/id name from inspect element.

Comment: You can also use ::nth-word approach .. Which is a css solution only

Comment: @SahilDhir ya but how do i split "Hear" and "us".? since it is in same span tag.?

Comment: :nth-word will select words individually.. You dont have to split them anymore.. The css selector will do the magic and you can add colors ..See this https://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/

Answer (score 1):

You should split by `space` character.

Change

```
$va = $("#section-56 .mid-content h1 span").text().split("");
```

To

```
$va = $("#section-56 .mid-content h1 span").text().split(" ");
```

Comment: If this is the answer, then the question should be closed as off-topic --- _"questions about a problem [...] that was caused by a simple typographical error"_.

Comment: Yes, because this kind of question does not help anyone except the OP. And now the OP has the solution, this question becomes of little help to others. Unless, of course, this isn't the solution to the question.

Comment: The question has just been edited to include `And how to i assign "Hear text as blue and Us text as Black"?`; personally I believe this should be a separate question.

Comment: @mamum i gave space, but alert is not working. alert($va);

Answer (score 1):

check below code if it help you.

```js
$va = $("span").text().split(" ");
$("span").html("<span class='blue'>"+$va[0] + "</span> <span class='red'>" + $va[1]);
```

```css
.red{color:red;}
.blue{color:blue}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <span>Hear Us</span>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should split by `space( )`. So the code should be this :

```js
$(function(){
  var a = $('span').text().split(" ");
  alert(a);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Hear Us</span>
```

It returns an array and you can access `a[0]`=Hear and `a[1]`=Us

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
$(function(){

$va = $("#section-56 .mid-content h1 span").text().split(" ");

    $va[0] = '<span style="color:blue;">'+ $va[0] +'</span>';
    $va[1] = '<span style="color:black;">'+ $va[1] +'</span>';

    $("#section-56 .mid-content h1 span").html($va[0] + " "+ $va[1]);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="section-56">
<div class="mid-content">
<h1>
<span>Hear Us</span>
</h1>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: i tried but not working. i tried to alert $va. but i'm not even getting alert.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is while using the separator as an empty string ("") instead of space (" ")

```
$va = $("#section-56 .mid-content h1 span").text().split(" ");
```

After getting the two words as an array using the above javascript code.
You need to construct the new content of h1 tag with two different span.

```
var newContent = '<span class="color-blue">'+$va[0]+'</span>'+' <span class="color-black">'+$va[1]+'</span>';

$("#section-56 .mid-content h1").html(newContent);
```

Finally, you need to change the css style for both words

```
#section-56 .mid-content h1 .color-blue{color: blue;}

#section-56 .mid-content h1 .color-blue{color: black;}
```

or alternatively you can simply add the css attributes inside the span tags

```
$va = $("#section-56 .mid-content h1 span").text().split(" ");
var newContent = '<span style="color: blue;">'+$va[0]+'</span>'+'<span style="color: black;">'+$va[1]+'</span>';

$("#section-56 .mid-content h1").html(newContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an exact solution (more than what you actually need), but I've done something in the past to style each word differently/randomly. http://codepen.io/Webpandit/pen/YXdXrg.

You could start here and change it to match your requirement. Should be a good task for you

```js
var pText = $('.text');
var words = pText.text().split(' ');
pText.text('');

for(var i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
  pText.append('<span class="textColor">' +words[i] + ' </span>');
}
var textColor = $('.textColor');

// arrays with property values
var colors = ['#000000', '#E843E2', '#666666', '#ff0000', '#00dd00', '#0063FF'];
var fontFamily = ['arial', 'helvetica', 'verdana', 'sans-serif'];
var fontStyle = ['italic', 'normal'];

// function to get a random Styles from the object passed in the function
var randomStyles = function(obj) {
  return obj[Math.floor(Math.random() * obj.length)];
}

// applying random styles to each word/span element
textColor.each(function(){
  $(this).css('color', randomStyles(colors));
  $(this).css('font-family', randomStyles(fontFamily));
  $(this).css('font-style', randomStyles(fontStyle));
});
```

```css
.text {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">Hello there this is a lorem ipsum text with random styles</div>
```

Edited: After you amend this script to your requirement, this could easily be extended to more words as well in case if your header text changes. I can post the answer later if you still don't get it to work

```js
var pText = $('.text');
var words = pText.text().split(' ');
pText.text('');

for(var i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
  pText.append('<span class="textColor">' +words[i] + ' </span>');
}

var textColor = $('.textColor');

// array with defined colors 
var definedColors = ['blue', 'black', 'red', 'orange', 'green', 'purple', 'brown', 'pink', 'grey', 'blue', 'black'];

// applying defined colors to each word/span element
textColor.each(function(index){
  $(this).css('color', definedColors[index]);
});
```

```css
.text {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">Styling three words</div>
```

UPDATE: This second snippet now answers your question exactly, the "definedColors" array should atleast have the same length (or more) as the number of words you are styling. This applies color to each word in the order they are in the array & not random as the previous snippet