# How to convert capitalized sentence into first word uppercase?

Tags: css, title-case

Input: I AM A STUDENT
Expected Output: I Am A Student
How can I achieve this using css?

Comment: If it's written capitalized within the code you cannot change it with CSS

Comment: With CSS, the closest you can come is uppercase the first letter of the sentence. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aKKPjL Otherwise, you need JavaScript.

Comment: How the input html looks like? Can you control it?

Comment: No I can't control it. Thanks got the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
p {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
p:first-line {
  display: block;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<p>I AM A STUDENT</p>
```

Comment: Great idea! I like the approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`text-transform`-property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp) of CSS if the text is lowercase to begin with:

```
p {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

If the text is already capitalized you unfortunately can only transform it into lowercase. Alternatively you could us the `::first letter`-selector like @Mr Lister suggested and put every word into a span like so:

```css
p {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
}

span::first-letter {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<p> <span>I</span> <span>AM</span> <span>A</span> <span>STUDENT</span> </p>
```

Other than that you could, of course, do this with JavaScript as discussed [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46853623/target-first-letter-of-each-word-in-css) but that should be a last resort.